# When using regex_replace(), what't the correct way to back-reference a submatch when it's directly followed by another digit in the format string?

Tags: c++, regex, c++11

In the following code, I tried to use `$1` to refer to the first submatch:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <regex>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string str {"1-2-3 4-5-6 7-8-9"};
    int r = 1;
    str = regex_replace(str, regex{R"((\d*-\d*-)\d*)"}, "$1" + to_string(r));
    cout << str << "\n";
    return 0;
}
```

What I expect is:

```
1-2-1 4-5-1 7-8-1
```

But it doesn't work because the actual format string passed to `regex_replace()` is `$11` as if I were trying to refer to the 11th submatch.

So when using `regex_replace()`, what is the correct way to back-reference a submatch which is followed directly by another digit in the format string?

I tried using `${1}` but it didn't work for any of the mainstream implementations that I tried.

Comment: Try `"$01" + to_string(r)`

Comment: @IgorTandetnik  `"$01"` does work.  Thanks for the suggestion.  Is it guaranteed that the no implementation will accept backreference number longer than 2 digits?

Comment: The current standards (C++ standard and JavaScript standard are involved) require it. An implementation that accepts longer back-references would be non-conforming.

Comment: Did `${1}` work for any implementation? If you could specify Perl rules for the fmt it probably would work. And whats that  specification stating its general. It uses `$&`,  `$‘`, `$’` all Perl constructs. Oh well..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to Standard N3337, §28.5.2, Table 139:

> `format_default`: When a regular expression match is to be replaced by a new string, the new string shall be constructed using the rules used
>   by the ECMAScript replace function in **ECMA-262, part 15.5.4.11
>   String.prototype.replace**. In addition, during search and replace
>   operations all non-overlapping occurrences of the regular expression
>   shall be located and replaced, and sections of the input that did not
>   match the expression shall be copied unchanged to the output string.

And according to [ECMA-262 part 15.5.4.11 String.prototype.replace](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.5.4.11), Table 22

> `$nn`: The nn-th capture, where nn is a two-digit decimal number in the range
>   01 to 99. If nn≤m and the nnth capture is undefined, use the empty
>   String instead. If nn>m, the result is implementation-defined.

So, there could be at most two decimal digits after `$`, which refers to matching group, therefore you could use

```
"$01" + to_string(r)
```